# Displaying HTML tags as webpage in asp.net page

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I am getting html code in *.aspx.vb page. I want to display this content as HTML or web page, but instead it is getting displayed as html code using response.write()

```
str_ = Server.HtmlEncode(GetTemplateContents("email_customerActivation.htm", asz))
Response.ContentType = "text/html"
Response.Write(str_)
```

Comment: There is no C# code in this question... Are you sure you've tagged it properly? Also it is very unclear what you trying to achieve and what does not work. Please [edit] post to replace `GetTemplateContents` with constant value as it does not seem you have problem in that function and clarify what results you expect from `Server.HtmlEncode`. Don't forget to tag [vb.net] if question is about VB.net code.

Comment: `Server.HtmlEncode` encodes `<tag>` to `&lt;tag&gt;` and browser decodes it back.

Answer (score 0):

i think you are trying to hard ! you have a special control for this purpose:
asp-Literal = set it's innet html to what ever you need and you are good to go!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/answering) and provide more details.